# React Native fetch state not update

Tags: state, fetch, react-native

Using the Fetch API on react native, this not update the ui after the promise done.

We realize the promise resolve when we touch the screen (yes, and update the ui with correct data).

For workarround, we use axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) and it resolve our problem.

Here is the code:

product-service.js

```
export class ProductsService {
    constructor() {
    }

    getProductDetail(id) {
        let url = 'http://myservice/product-detail/' + id;
        return fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

my-component.js

```
export class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            product: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
         let productService = new ProductsService();
         productService.getProductDetail(1)
            .then((productDetail) => {
                console.log('updateProduct: ', productDetail);
                this.setState({
                    product: productDetail
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.product.name}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

When we use fetch, the name of the product appear only if we touch the device screen.
When we use axios, it works.

It's a bug?

Environment: Windows 10, Android 6, React Native 0.31

Comment: I think it is RN fetch bug.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not using react native, but, had the same problem just now. The thing is **this.setState** when the promise resolves doesn't point to the component.

Before the fetch call i stored **this** on a var

```
const thiz = this;
```

and then used **thiz** var to set the state

```
thiz.setState({});
```

or you could bind the function to **thiz**

```
then((function(){
    this.setState({});
}).bind(thiz))
```